# iOS: WKWebView does not load local JS files immediately

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview, lottie

I'm loading two JS files into a `WKWebView` via `loadHTMLstring` method. The scripts are embedded in the application so no HTTP call is being executed. The first script is loaded in the `head` tag. The second is inline. This is for Lottie web player: https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player. So, the first one loads `lottie-player.js` whereas the second one loads an animation after the `lottie-player` element.

The second script does something similar to:

```
const player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");

// or load via a Bodymovin JSON string/object
player.load(
  '{"v":"5.3.4","fr":30,"ip":0,"op":38,"w":315,"h":600,"nm":"new", ... }'
);
```

Everything works fine (i.e. the animation loads and plays). The problem I'm facing is it takes about 1 second before the animation becomes visible, so `WKWebView` doesn't seem to load the scripts immediately. Is there a way to fix this issue? I'm using a default `WKWebViewConfiguration`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample project like an xcode playground project possibly where the issue is reproducible?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is a bit complex to provide a sample right now. The `WKWebView` is a child of a vertical `UIStackView` which is then the background view for a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKWebView initialization and first load are slow. It is better you initialize and load WKWebView before the view controller containing your WKWebView is loaded. You can use below project to check how they have achieved this for your reference and also they have done comparison of time taken to load.

https://github.com/bernikovich/WebViewWarmUper

Also hope that loading an animation is not taking much time.

Comment: Thanks. I actually implemented something similar last night, and it seems to be working for now.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this solution. It seems to work fine 80% of the time. Sometimes, I get blank screens even though the views are warmed up and maintained in a shared object. Any idea why this could be happening?